# Laravel best approach for Testing if a value will change

Tags: laravel, testing, optimization, updates

#### The code

I have a database, which has a table for Teams and Instructors along the lines of:

```
| id | team_id | instructor_id | ... |
```

Every 24 hours a batch runs that updates the instructor for that team.
What I need to create is a simple Test to check if the batch is running properly, and the instructor is changed.

#### The Issue

The batch updates the instructor **randomly**, meaning that the same instructor might get chosen twice, throwing an error when running the test. I tried checking if the `updated_at` column changes, but it seems like when the same values are passed to `update()` Laravel does not change said column.

#### The question

How am I supposed to check if the instructor changes?
I am only assigned to making the test, so I should not change the way the batch operates (like forcing it so that `updated_at` changes)
However making a for loop until the instructor is changed looks very ugly.
And since there are only between 3 to 5 instructors, the chances of the same instructor being picked a few times in a row is not that low.

### Update

Here is the code as requested.
The test file:

```
class InstructorSelectionOrderTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    ...

    /**
     * @test
     * @group instructorSelection
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_old_team_instructor_random()
    {
        $team = factory(RoutineTeam::class)->create(['instructor_id' => 4, 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->subDays(1)]);
        $room = factory(Room::class)->create(['team_id' => $team->id]);

        $this->createNewUser($team->id, $room->id);

        $this->artisan('project:reassign_instructors')->assertExitCode(0);

        $result = RoutineTeam::where('id', $team->id)->get();

        $this->assertFalse($result[0]->updated_at == $team->updated_at);
    }
```

The batch:

```
class ReassignInstructors extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'project:reassign_instructors';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //list of rooms that needs to be updated
        $routineTeams = RoutineTeam::openedRoomTeams();

        ...

        foreach ($routineTeams as $routineTeam) {
            //Instructor::getRandomInstructor()->id = random number from 1 to 4
            $routineTeam->instructor_id = Instructor::getRandomInstructor()->id;
            $routineTeam->save();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

The RoutineTeam table:

```
| id | team_id | instructor_id | ... | updated_at
```

The test currently has a 25% chance of failing. I can only edit the test file. Is there a way to make it a 0% chance of failing only by changing the test file?

Comment: 5 instructors, chances of the same instructor is picked is 20%. anyway, share the code that chooses the new instructor,  you can easily exclude the old instructor id each time or force update `updated_at` each time.

Comment: Unfortunately I have been told not to exclude the old instructor. So would force updating the ```updated_at``` be the best approach?

Comment: As written, I am only assigned to making the test, so I cannot change the batch so it force updates the column. @N69S

Comment: We need some pseudo code, or approaches to be able to reproduce this. Right now this question does not follow the stackoverflow standard. You talk about testing? but you know you control all the data and the randomness in a test environment if you want. I really want to see, how you pick the random instructor?

Comment: I will be adding a shortened version of the code in more details in a moment, but I cannot see why it needs to be reproduced since it throws no errors. @mrhn

Comment: If we cant reproduce it it is hard to help, i dont know how you random the instructor or how the command code is. In general stackoverflow is for errors or unexpected behavior, not design philosophies. Therefor we need reproduceable code. [Good questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you are here just to discuss ideas, then you're at the wrong place since your question will be opinion based.

Comment: The good questions on SO says "not all questions benefit from code" and I assumed this is one of those cases? I guess a piece of code might help nonetheless... @mrhn

Comment: I see. I was looking for possible improvement/adjustment, and thought it would be fine since there was an "improvement" tag in recommendations. @N69S

Comment: Thanks for the feedback anyways! It helps to understand why a question got downvoted.

Comment: Is there a foreign key constraint on `instructor_id` or can it take an unexisting instructor_id value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the instructor id is static in your test, I'm guessing there is no foreign key constraint on it.

So, why not set the instructor_id to 0 and then run the job (or any non existing id).

```php
 /**
     * @test
     * @group instructorSelection
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_old_team_instructor_random()
    {
        //setting the id to 0 so it is forced to change on 'project:reassign_instructors' command
        $team = factory(RoutineTeam::class)->create(['instructor_id' => 0, 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->subDays(1)]);
        $room = factory(Room::class)->create(['team_id' => $team->id]);

        $this->createNewUser($team->id, $room->id);

        $this->artisan('project:reassign_instructors')->assertExitCode(0);

        $result = RoutineTeam::where('id', $team->id)->get();

        $this->assertFalse($result[0]->updated_at == $team->updated_at);
    }
```

Comment: That worked! I had assumed a foreign key must have been set, as a table called "instructor" existed, but after checking the SQL I noticed that although there was a table for it, there was no constraint set for the column!